# Hosting Windows Guest Containers in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I can't get a simple container deployed to a single node on a development cluster installed on Windows 2016 Datacenter w/ Containers. The package deploys but the Partition status is always "In Build". I've included the Application and Service manifests below.

I can remote into the machine and run the container manually using the following command:

```
docker run --name nanoiis -d -it -p 80:80 nanoserver/iis.
```

When the container is running, I can get to the instance of IIS running in it from a remote machine. I can't get to the container using localhost from the host due to the documented NAT issue.

Now I need to get the container running in Service Fabric. I have 5.4.145.9494 installed. I understand container support in this version of the runtime is in preview but shouldn't this simple use case work?

**Application Manifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest ApplicationTypeName="ContainerSampleType"
                   ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="IISContainer_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="1" />
  </Parameters>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="IISContainerPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <Policies>      
      <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code">        
        <PortBinding ContainerPort="80" EndpointRef="IISContainerTypeEndpoint"/>        
      </ContainerHostPolicies>
    </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="IISContainer">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="IISContainerType" InstanceCount="[IISContainer_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

**Service Manifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="IISContainerPkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="IISContainerType" UseImplicitHost="true" />
  </ServiceTypes>
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ContainerHost>
        <ImageName>nanoserver/iis:latest</ImageName>        
      </ContainerHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0" />
  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Name="IISContainerTypeEndpoint" UriScheme="http" Protocol="http" Port="80"/>
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the fact that the default MS images don't explicitly expose port 80. ASF does require this (atm)

Simply add it yourself like:

```
FROM nanoserver/iis
EXPOSE 80
```

And push it to docker hub, or your own registry.

Read the blog post [here](https://loekd.blogspot.nl/2017/01/running-windows-containers-on-azure.html) to get a simple IIS container running on ASF.
Read the post [here](https://loekd.blogspot.nl/2017/01/running-windows-containers-on-azure_10.html) to troubleshoot.